# Assign parent ids to children of multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to assign parent ids to all the children of a multidimensional array in PHP.

```
Array
(
    [expanded] => 1
    [key] => root_1
    [title] => root
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [folder] => 1
                    [key] => 34
                    [title] => YAY PROJECTS
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [expanded] => 1
                    [folder] => 1
                    [key] => 6
                    [title] => Grand Designs Episodes
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [folder] => 1
                                    [key] => 8
                                    [title] => AU Episodes
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [expanded] => 1
                                    [folder] => 1
                                    [key] => 7
                                    [title] => UK Episodes
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [folder] => 
                                                    [key] => 9
                                                    [title] => Start something
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [folder] => 
                                                    [key] => 2
                                                    [title] => Grand Designs Season 10
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [expanded] => 1
                    [folder] => 1
                    [key] => 5
                    [title] => Animations
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [folder] => 
                                    [key] => 4
                                    [title] => Futurama Episode 191
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [folder] => 
                                    [key] => 3
                                    [title] => Miniscule Series 5 Ep 1
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [folder] => 
                                    [key] => 1
                                    [title] => The Simpsons Episode 459
                                )
                        )
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [folder] => 1
                    [key] => 11
                    [title] => Test Folder
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [folder] => 1
                    [key] => 10
                    [title] => Testing
                )
        )
)
```

At first I thought this would be fairly trivial, however my solution quickly falls apart assigning the wrong parent_ids.

```
public function generateParentIds(array $input, $parentId = 0)
    {
        $return = [];

        foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

            if (is_array($value)) {

                $value = $this->generateParentIds($value, $parentId);

                if (isset($value['children'])) {
                    $parentId = $value['key'];
                }

                if (!is_int($key)) {
                    $return['parent_id'] = $parentId;
                }
            }

            $return[$key] = $value;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

I'm not sure whats going on, I did a lot of research but couldn't find any examples, so I'd be very grateful for some help.

Comment: Which are the parent ids? Does the top level parent id get assigned to all of the descendants, or does each array get the parent id of its direct parent?

Comment: What is your expected output? It would be easier to understand without making a qualified guess.

Comment: Sorry, i should have clarified. Each child needs the key of the direct parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each child should get the immediate parent's `key` value as its `parent_id`, this should do what you want. Note that it modifies the array in place (`$input` is passed by reference to the function, and the foreach loop uses a reference to `$child`), rather than attempting to merge returned values.

```
function generateParentIds(&$input, $parentId = 0) {
    $input['parent_id'] = $parentId;
    if (isset($input['children'])) {
        foreach ($input['children'] as &$child) {
            generateParentIds($child, $input['key']);
        }
    }
}

generateParentIds($input);
```

Output is too long to show here but there's a [demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8NLrD)

Comment: Thank-you Nick! Using the reference makes so much more sense.